# WPF FixedDocument background image

Tags: c#, wpf

Where to put the Background Image for a FixedDocument ? I see it in FlowDocument, but not in FixedDocument.

In FlowDocument

```
  <FlowDocument.Background>
    <ImageBrush>
        <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
            <!--Image source here...-->
        </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
    </ImageBrush>
  </FlowDocument.Background>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using this way :

```
<FixedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06"
Width="793.60" Height="1122.56" xml:lang="fr">
    <Canvas>
        <Path Data="M 0.00,0.00 L 0.00,3508.00 L 2480.00,3508.00 L 2480.00,0.00 Z">
            <Path.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="xxx.jpg"
                            TileMode="None"
                            Viewbox="0,0,3306.67,4677.33"
                            ViewboxUnits="Absolute"
                            Viewport="0.00,0.00,2480.00,3508.00"
                            ViewportUnits="Absolute"/>
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
    ...
    </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set it page by page using [`FixedPage.Background`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.fixedpage.background%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for each fixed page:

```
        <DocumentViewer Name="mainRTB" >
            <FixedDocument>
                <FixedDocument.Resources>
                    <ImageBrush x:Key="backgroundImage" TileMode="Tile" Stretch="Fill" Viewport="0,0,1.0,0.33333333" AlignmentX="Center">
                        <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                            <!--Image source here...-->
                        </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                    </ImageBrush>
                </FixedDocument.Resources>
                <PageContent>
                    <!-- 7" x 9" page -->
                    <FixedPage Width="672" Height="864" Background="{StaticResource backgroundImage}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" FixedPage.Left="280" FixedPage.Top="150">
                            <Label FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" Content="Jane Eyre" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Label FontFamily="Arial" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="14" Content="Charlotte Brontë" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </FixedPage>
                </PageContent>
                <PageContent>
                    <FixedPage Width="672" Height="864" Background="{StaticResource backgroundImage}">
                        <StackPanel Margin="48">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Cambria" FontSize="14" Width="576" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                There was no possibility etc.
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Cambria" FontSize="14" Width="576" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,25,0,0">
                I was glad of it etc.
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </FixedPage>
                </PageContent>
            </FixedDocument>
        </DocumentViewer>
```

Seems like it prints too -- at least I saw my background image show up when printing to PDF995.